# webpack build was successful, but I cannot use it

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I've built a React component for testing purposes that will be kept confidential.

I use Node.js version 9 and React version 15.6.2.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.6.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.15.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "7.15.0",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "webpack": "^4.46.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

/src/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

root index.js

```
module.exports = require('./dist/bundle');
```

this is successfully build.

but, using this package in my project.

```
import TestComponent from 'library';
```

in browser error print.

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure what's causing it. Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason why all the versions you use and coding style are outdated?

Comment: @Arkellys Yes, it should be available for legacy projects...

Comment: I solved it by attaching output: { ..., libraryTarget: 'umd' } to the webpack.